# Android - performence is getting low after few seconds

Tags: android, asynchronous

Im using the following code to increment numbers of 30 TextViews very fast.
Everythig is working well for the first maybe 30 steps. After that the change is very slow.

```
        handler = new Handler();
        updater = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                About30Textviews.increment;
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 10);
            }
        };
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                handler.post(updater);
            }
        });
```

Can somebody explain why? Or anybody knows a solution?
Thx a lot!

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are really doing here.  Do you have 30 different calls, one for each text view of .increment?  Do you call all of this each step?

Comment: the function increment in the About30Textviews class has a loop within every single textviews text (which is a number) is incremented by 1.